# Double Click after a Drag and Drop

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

After I drag and drop a label(or other UIComponent) in a container, i want to double click the label to show me an alert. well it doesn't work.

i've tried in the dragCompleteHandler to put event.dragIntiator.addEventListener or event.currentTargetaddEventListner but it doesn't work. Also i enabled the DoubleClickEnabler and still nothing?

Any ideas because i tried to google it and nothing came out with this problem.

thanks

Comment: sorry, i wasn't aware i had to do that but you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To capture a double-click event on a `UIComponent` (or more generally, an `InteractiveObject`), set both its [`mouseEnabled`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#mouseEnabled) and [`doubleClickEnabled`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#doubleClickEnabled) properties to `true` and add a [`MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#DOUBLE_CLICK) event listener.

```
iaObject.doubleClickEnabled = true;
iaObject.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK, doubleClickHandler);
```

The `mouseEnabled` property should be set to `true` by default, but it could have been flipped by the dragging code.  You might want to check it in your debugger to be sure.